# Accessing some websites fails on wireless but works fine on a wired connection

Tags: wireless-networking

I have 3 Linksys WRT3200ACM routers: 1 connected to a modem (which has router as a DMZ just in case), the remaining 2 routers are connected to the first router on LAN ports and configured to work as a bridge. All three have 5GHz wireless enabled (same SSID and password), one has 2.4GHz for older devices.

The problem I experience is that on wireless connection some websites randomly fail to respond and pinging (zim-wiki.org for example) fails with a 100% packet loss. It happens on different OSes (linux, macOS, windows, android) and on devices connected to any of the 3 routers.

I have disabled DHCP on a modem (it was causing issues before), disabled firewall there too (the main Linksys router acts as one), basically tried to make our modem to do one and one thing only.

Finding out correct MTU value (1472) and setting it might have helped with some websites but that is just a feeling with no real proof.

I had configured 3 different wireless networks but the issue remains.

The next step I plan to do is installing LEDE firmware on one of the routers tomorrow and playing with signal strength, etc.

I'm not a network engineer so most of the stuff I tried is based on browsing google and previous experience.

Some extra information:

- Modem uses 192.168.0.0/24 (IP: 192.168.0.1), main router is 192.168.1.0/24 (IP: 192.168.1.1), the bridged routers have static IPs: 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3
- DHCP start-end: 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.224 (max 125 clients?)
- Using ethernet cable solves the issue but that's not an acceptable solution
- I have all three routers on a narrow (20MHz) channels, all three use separate channels to reduce noise (noise levels are way lower than the other random wireless networks around).
- I have reset all three routes multiple times and reconfigured again just in case

Have anyone experience same or similar issue before and have any advice or two?

[UPDATE] Installed LEDE on all three routers and used similar topography (moved to 172.16.0.0/16). So far everything works smoothly, will report back on Monday once we have all of the users connected at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is an issue with the recent Android/Google products update (2017 November I think) where they push a lot of packets on the network and distrupts wireless network cause some routers start dropping packets to prevent/mitigate packet flood.

Relevant discussion: https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT32x-and-WRT3200ACM-WiFi-Issues/td-p/1246764